# Rails scope with constraints

Tags: ruby-on-rails

On my Rails6 app I want to allow specific routes to be loaded for different languages, using :locale variable.

```
scope '(/:locale)' do
    resources :posts
end
```

It works...

```
/IT/POSTS
/DE/POSTS
/POSTS (will default to it)
```

But non-existent URL paths are interpreted like locales (for eg. website.com/FAKEPATH)

I want to match specific locales: it, de. And raise 404 otherwise.

I tried like this:

```
scope '(/:locale)', locale: /it|de/, defaults: { locale: "it" }
scope '(/:locale)', constraints: { locale: /it|de/ }
```

But it doesn't work.

Any hep?

------ UPDATE / SOLVED

Outside the scope I had this line...

```
get '/:locale', to: 'pages#index'
```

this was absorbing the requests.

I changed it into:

```
get '/:locale', to: 'pages#index', constraints: { locale: Regexp.union(I18n.available_locales.map(&:to_s)) }
```

now I see a 404 error when accessing wrong URLs.

Comment: Scope `scope '(/:locale)', locale: /it|de/` will work. But setting the default should not be done in your routes. It should be done via `I18n.default_locale`.  `scope '(/:locale)', locale: Regexp.union(I18n.available_locales)` is even better as it lets you consolidate the locale configuration into an initializer file instead of duplicating it in mulitple places in your app (there should be only one source of truth). https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#setting-the-locale-from-url-params

Comment: You're going to have to be more specific then `it doesn't work`. Can you tell us exactly what you treid and what went wrong? Or even better do you have a failing test?

Comment: If it was caused by a problem that can't be reproduced its better to just delete the question then to add an edit as it won't be helpful to others anyways.

Comment: It is helpful! @Mich Dart Thanks for posting this question. I have experienced exactly the same problem. Adding constraints to get '/:locale' resolved my issue.